# Catch a throw Exception from another class

Tags: php

Library Class

Library.php

```
<?php

namespace Namepp\Exa;

class Library
{
 // Check if this token has expired.
        if (isset($payload) {
            throw new ExpiredException('Expired!');
        }
```

Exception Class
ExpiredException.php

```
<?php
namespace Namepp\Exa;

class ExpiredException extends \UnexpectedValueException
{

}
```

How I am on my own system, I use composer autoload the library.

```
<?php
use \Namepp\Exa\Library;

class ControllerLit extends Controller {

public function index() {

    try{
        $example= Library::callThis();
    }catch(Exception $e){
         echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

When I run this file, I got the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception '\Namepp\Exa\ExpiredException' with
>   message 'Expired!' in
>   C:\www\project\vendor\namepp\exa\src\Library.php:119 Stack trace: #0

My goal is I do not have Fatal error, I want my script able to continue after the catch. Anything I miss out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are under the global space (there is no `namespace` declaration as I see). In this case you have two option when you call the class:

- Use the `use` operator
- Use the fully qualified class name

In first case

```
<?php
use \Namepp\Exa\Library;
use Namepp\Exa\ExpiredException;

class ControllerLit extends Controller {
    /* ... */
    try{
        $example= Library::callThis();
    } catch( ExpiredException $e){
         echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
```

In second case

```
try{
    $example= Library::callThis();
} catch( \Namepp\Exa\ExpiredException $e){
     echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using specific exception class in try/catch:

```
<?php

use Namepp\Exa\Library;
use Namepp\Exa\ExpiredException;

class ControllerLit extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        try {
             $example= Library::callThis();
        } catch (ExpiredException $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party, however, you can for uncaught exceptions use the following.

In any file that's always loaded (class Controller maybe) after the classes closing brace add the following.

```
// A user-defined exception handler function
function uncaught_exception_handler($e) {
    echo '<b>Uncaught Exception</b> ' . $e->getMessage() . ': ' . $e->getFile() . '(' . $e->getLine() . ')';
}

// Set user-defined exception handler function
set_exception_handler('uncaught_exception_handler');
```

This is a modification of the code at this page from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_error_set_exception_handler.asp)

They pretty much have it covered, however I prefer to include the file and line number in the report so I can quickly fix the issue without digging through multiple files as can often be the case when working with class patterns that span many files and paths.